# Openssl SSL_accept() fails with Unknown Protocol

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, tls1.2

Edit  - 
I changed

```
method = SSLv23_server_method(); to 
method = TLSv1_2_server_method()
```

;

Now SSL_accept() gives me back a wrong version number error.

```
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:386:
```

When I listed the SSL and TLS versions in use on my system -

```
openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
SSLv3
TLSv1.2
```

What am I missing here ?

---

@jww -> Tagging you coz I noticed you answered a few qs related to openssl. Hope you dont mind

I am running into an issue with SSL_accept() in my server code. I am using openssl 1.0.2g. After much research, I could not find the real reason for the error.

Here is my server code -

```
open socket , bind to socket, listen on socket

initialize SSL context and libraries. Load certificate and Private key files
{
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    method = SSLv23_server_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, ccrt, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
    }
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, ckey, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
         ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);

}

pselect() waits on any incoming connections or any reads on existing connections

if new connection - accept() the connection and add to the pselect FD_SET and return

if existing connection, there is something to read so do the following {
    SSL *ssl;
    if ( !ctx )
    {
       return 0;
    }
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, soc);
    int ret = SSL_accept(ssl); --> FAILS
    if (ret <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
     return 0}
 }
```

When the error queue is printed it shows -

```
error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:640:
```

Is this a version mismatch (Openssl 1.0.2g) ?

Comment: I just listed the SSL and TLS versions : openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq - 
SSLv3
TLSv1.2

Comment: But it looks like SSLv3 is disabled by default in 1.0.2g per this - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.2g-1ubuntu1.  So I am confused as to which method I should be using for ubuntu 18.04